# full outer join matching on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, outer-join

Two tables I am trying to join:

**tableA**: this table contains all of the leads we won by BID and by SOURCE and by DATE.

```
Bid Amount = tableA.price, Source = tableA.lead_source_id, Date = tableA.time
```

**tableB**: this table contains all of the leads we lost by BID and by SOURCE and by DATE.

```
Bid Amount = tableB.cost, Source = tableB.lead_source_id, Date = tableB.bid_at
```

I would like to be able to return the number of bids we WON and LOST by BID and by SOURCE and by DATE. Often times there are only records in one table or the other (we won all bids or lost all bids), so it appears the outer join is needed.

Ideal output would be grouped by lead_source_id, bid amount, and time like such:

```
Lead Source ID, Date, Bid Amount, Won, Lost

1, 1/1/2015, $20, 5, 0 

1, 1/1/2015, $25, 0, 9

5, 1/1/2015, $30, 1, 1

10, 1/2/2015, $50, 0, 1

10, 1/2/2015, $55, 1, 0
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what means the third row in your example (5, 1/1/2015, $30, 1, 1)? Is the value $30 (Bid Amount) the difference between 'Won' and 'Lost'? Would be better if you add initial data for this example.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion and thank you for responding. The third row would indicate: on 1/1/2015, for lead_source_id = 5, there was one bid won for $30 in tableA (tableA.price = $30, tableA.lead_source_id = 5, tableA.time = 1/1/2015) AND one bid lost for $30 in tableB (tableB.cost = $30, tableB.lead_source_id = 5, tableB.bid_at = 1/1/2015).

Comment: Thanks for the response, Olga. Getting the following: " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tmp AS (
SELECT lead_source_id,  [time] AS [Date], price, COUNT(*) AS won, 0 AS ' at line 1"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query.

```
;WITH tmp AS (
SELECT lead_source_id,  [time] AS [Date], price, COUNT(*) AS won, 0 AS lost 
FROM  tableA
GROUP BY lead_source_id, [time], price 
UNION ALL
SELECT lead_source_id, bid_at AS [Date], cost AS price, 0 AS won, COUNT(*) AS lost 
FROM tableB
GROUP BY lead_source_id, bid_at, cost)

SELECT lead_source_id AS [Lead Source ID], [Date], price AS [Bid Amount], SUM(won) AS Won , SUM(lost) AS Lost
FROM tmp
GROUP BY lead_source_id, [Date], price
ORDER BY lead_source_id, [Date]
```

The common table expression (tmp) calculates number of won/lost bids and the outer select groups your data by id, date and bid amounts.